# Why can't I push my tag to remote when I created this tag from a branch that's remote?

Tags: git, debugging, github

I've created a tag called `v1.0` off of a remote branch called `v-2.5` and now I'm trying to push this tag to remote so I can deploy on Jenkins.

When I try to push I get:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

So what I did was `git push origin HEAD:v-2.5`  but my output is `Everything up-to-date`.
Am I missing something here?

My attempts have been the ones I've been seeing on SO but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Add `-t` to your push command to push tags.

Comment: @RomainValeri so while I'm checked out to my `v1.0` tag, I should run `git push -t` and that'd push to remote?  I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to check anything out. `-t` in the push command pushes all known tags to the remote.

Comment: What command did you use to push? And what is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Technically, when you do `git checkout <tag>`, you're no longer on *any* branch.  Git doesn't actually need any branches to work.  Branches are for puny humans, not for computers! But once you're on *no* branch, you *must* specify what to push, because the default is to push the current branch, and there isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push a specific tag:

```
git push origin v1.0
```

Push all tags:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: yeah... I just saw a post regarding this, thanks man and apologies to waste your time.

Comment: git ls-remote --tags origin
27126f74b9390ff688c71a3a53ba2d26f7257b92        refs/tags/Ukxrnd1b
e47132604def6b3a41bbb3a6e3e47cd82ba81ec4        refs/tags/Ukxrnd1b^{}
What is the 2nd tag and why it is created?

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear: `fatal: You are not currently on a branch.` You can fix this by either checking out an existing branch:

```
git checkout v-2.5
```

or creating a new one creating a branch:

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch
```

Then you can push that branch and any tags on it:

```
git push --tags origin <branch name>
```